# Why use recursion on a pre order traversal (binary search tree)?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I have these 3 different traversal methods below, which traverses my binary search tree. I know that both post order and in-order traversal is from the bottom to the root, but preorder is from root to the bottom. Since recursion goes bottom up, why do we use recursion on preorder traversal? All the preorder examples I could find uses recursion.

```
private void preOrder(BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Empty");
        }
        if(t != null) {
            System.out.println(t.element);
            preOrder(t.left);
            preOrder(t.right);
        }
    }

    private void postOrder(BinaryNode<AnyType> t){

        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Empty");
        }
        if (t != null) {
            postOrder(t.left);
            postOrder(t.right);
            System.out.println(t.element);
        }
    }

    private void inOrder(BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
    {
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Empty");
        }

        if (t != null) {
            inOrder(t.left);
            System.out.println(t.element);
            inOrder(t.right);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the point is *when* we print a node of the tree.

Postorder: `System.out.println` is placed *after* all recursion calls, so algorithm goes through all nodes till the end and *after* that starts to print them.

For preorder case, current node is printed and after that subtrees are processed.

---

There is no rules like "recursion goes bottom up or top down". But if you have some code *before* recursion call it will be executed top down. If you have some code after recursion call, it will be executed bottom up.

Comment: Thanks, that made sense.